# The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/SimpleStockQuoteService

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm a newbie in wso2 ESB. I am following the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service) and trying out the "REST Client and SOAP Service" scenario. After executing

`ant stockquote -Daddurl=http://localhost:8280/services/StockQuoteProxy -Drest=true`

the following error is thrown
     **[java] Sending as REST
     [java] org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/SimpleStockQuoteService and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the ant command without the last part as below

```
ant stockquote -Daddurl=http://localhost:8280/services/StockQuoteProxy
```